# Предлог «об» или «о»?

Tags: untagged

В предложении: «Ходатайствовать о ее изменении (мере пресечения)». Верно ли употребление предлога «о»?

Answer (score 3):

Правильно "О её". Хотя буква здесь гласная (Е), первый звук её согласный "й". Потому его не надо отграничивать буквой "б".